# amplify: how to set up configuration files for auth and api

Tags: installation, deployment, configuration, aws-amplify

I develop a project with amplify.

I have created a cognito pool for authentication and a REST api with an endpoint. I want my endpoint to work with the cognito pool. In order to achieve that, I have created in `API Gateway` console an `Authorizer` working with cognito and then changed the `ANY` method to use my  authorizer.

It works perfectly.

Now I want to deploy my project on another aws account. As mentioned [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/tools/cli/migration/cli-migrate-aws-account/), I can do it without further action on my code.

The thing is I set up authentication for my endpoint on the console : it is not reflected in my codebase.

How can I setup config files in `amplify/backend` directory to create my authorizer and make it used by my endpoints ?